# dataDetectorTypes phone link issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

this is a reformulation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913802/uiwebview-phone-links-detection-on-iphone)

When i set **myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;** phone links (in a href html tag) are handled like this :

[image]

How can I handle phone links with the **shouldStartLoadWithRequest** delegate method instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not still found the cause of the problem but I found a solution.

Instead of writing phone links in anchors like this *tel:myphonenumber*, i write *allo:myphonenumber*.

Thus, the **shouldStartLoadWithRequest** method is called. And i can substitute *allo:* by *tel:* in my `NSURLRequest` object.

edit, here is the code :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {

      NSURL *requestURL = [[ request URL] retain];
      // Check to see what protocol/scheme the requested URL is.

      if ( 
          // ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] ) &&
          ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )
          ) {

        // Stats
        [self recordTouch: [self tagToZone:[[webView superview] tag]]];

        // Substitution allo -> tel
        NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: [[[request URL] absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"allo:" withString: @"tel:"]];
        [requestURL release];

        //return YES;

        // Launch
        return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [newURL autorelease]];
      }

      // Auto release
      [requestURL release];
      return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Lefakir,

could you put up the code of how you did it? Calling UIWebView:loadrequest with the newRequest wont work because the message will still come up. changing the NSURLRequest wont work either because it is read only.

Comment: Lefakir,

  could you put up the code of how you did it? Calling UIWebView:loadrequest with the newRequest wont work because the message will still come up. changing the NSURLRequest wont work either because it is read only.