# How to change the color of numbers and emails in UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I have one String that contains tags. I am loading this string to UIWebView. Before that I am formatting it like this

```
    NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"<html>"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                   "body { background-color:transparent; font-family:Times Helvetica Neue,Georgia,sans-serif; font-size:14;}"
                                   "</style>"
                                   "<body>"
                                   "<p>%@</p>"
                                   "</body></html>", deal.dealDescription];
```

However, there are numbers and emails with BLUE COLOUR. I want remove that blue colour. See image:

[image]

I want to remove this from FORMATTING HTML. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView is detecting the number and turning it into a hyperlink. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913802/uiwebview-phone-links-detection-on-iphone).

Briefly, you specify what link types you want to handle using a bitmask, so for instance if you wanted to handle web links but nothing else, you could do:-

```
self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

or to detect all links *except* a phone number, use:-

```
self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = ~UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

Note if your webview is created inside a nib/storyboard, there are checkboxes that control this behaviour in Interface Builder too.

**EDIT:**

To just change the colour of your hyperlink, simply add some CSS styling, for example add this to your HTML string, next to your body style definition.

`"a:link { color:#FFFFFF; }"`

Comment: It is still blue. It didn't work

I want only colour change, but it must be a number which is clickable, as it is right now.

Comment: OK, well that was not clear in your original question. In that case, you just need to add some CSS styling to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tintColor of the UIWebView (iOS 7 only).

```
myWebView.tintColor = [UIColor yourColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

user this meta tag in head section. that blue color remove.

```
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
```